# Use python multiprocessing queue to write to a shelve file

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shelve

I met a problem with python multiprocessing.

I have a .csv file (~ 10 GB). I want to read data from it, transform the data and then save it into a python shelve file. The data transformation is quite slow, so I am thinking about multiprocessing.

I create two multiprocess queues, the first to save data read from csv, and the second to save data after being transformed. These two queues are working fine; however, the issue is that the process which write data to shelve from the second queue stops after a couple of hours.

Anyone met the same problem? Thanks for any suggestion!

My code is here:

```
def read_from_csv(csv_path, csv_queue):
    count = 0
    fh =  open(csv_path, 'r')
    for line in fh:
        try:
            text, ID = line.split('|')
            text = text.split()
            ID = ID.strip()
            data = (ID, text)
            csv_queue.put(data, True)
            count += 1

            n = csv_queue.qsize()
            if n > 0 and  n % 10000 == 0:
                logger.info('Queue size is {}'.format(n))

            # Let the function sleep for a while to prevent the queue becoming too long
            if n >= 100000:
                logger.info('CSV queue sleeps for 100 sec')
                time.sleep(100)
            if count % 10000 == 0:
                logger.info('Read {} lines'.format(count))
        except:
            pass
    logger.info('Done feeding rows into the Queue')



def entities_extraction(csv_queue, shelve_queue):
    count = 0
    while not csv_queue.empty():
        try:
            item = csv_queue.get(True, 300)
        except:
            logger.info('Not able to fetch data from queue. Quitting')
            break

        # some function here
        # result = ......

        shelve_queue.put(result, True)
        count += 1

        n = shelve_queue.qsize()
        if count % 10000 == 0:
            logger.info('Process {} lines'.format(count))

        # Let the function sleep for a while to prevent the queue becoming too long
        if n > 100000:
            logger.info('Shelve queue sleeps for 100 sec')
            time.sleep(100)


def write_to_shelve(shelve_file, csv_queue, shelve_queue):


    sh = shelve.open(shelve_file, writeback=True)
    count = 0

    while True:
        if count % 10000 == 0:
            logger.info("Written {} records".format(count))

        n = shelve_queue.qsize()
        if n > 0 and n % 10000 == 0:
            logger.info('Shelve queue size is {}'.format(n))
        #if count > 50000:
        #    print('stop')
        #    break
        try:
            item = shelve_queue.get(True, 600)
            id, token = item
            sh[id] = token
            count += 1

        except:
            logger.info("Not able to fetch data from queue. Quitting")
            #time.sleep(5)
            break
    sh.close()



if __name__ == "__main__":

    t0 = time.time()
    csv_path =  
    shelve_path =  

    csv_queue = mp.Manager().Queue()
    shelve_queue = mp.Manager().Queue()


    process_to_launch = 7
    pool = mp.Pool(process_to_launch)

    pool.apply(read_from_csv, (csv_path, csv_queue,))

    jobs = [pool.apply(entities_extraction, (csv_queue, shelve_queue,)) for i in range(5)]

    result = pool.apply(write_to_shelve, (shelve_path, csv_queue, shelve_queue,))

    #sh.close()
    print(time.time() - t0)


pool.close()
pool.join()
```

And part of the logging info is:

```
[2017-03-24 20:42:54,562 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-10] - 83 - INFO - Written 2900000 records
[2017-03-24 20:42:54,779 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-3] - 43 - INFO - Read 3070000 lines
[2017-03-24 20:42:55,919 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-3] - 38 - INFO - Queue size is 90000
[2017-03-24 20:42:59,047 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-3] - 43 - INFO - Read 3080000 lines
[2017-03-24 20:43:02,846 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-3] - 38 - INFO - Queue size is 100000
[2017-03-24 20:43:02,847 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-3] - 40 - INFO - CSV queue sleeps for 100 sec
[2017-03-24 20:43:08,426 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-10] - 87 - INFO - Shelve queue size is 80000

### The writing function stopped here

0.04154396057128906
[2017-03-24 20:44:30,812 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-5] - 68 - INFO - Process 500000 lines
[2017-03-24 20:44:32,745 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-4] - 68 - INFO - Process 500000 lines
[2017-03-24 20:44:34,104 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-8] - 68 - INFO - Process 500000 lines
[2017-03-24 20:44:43,091 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-3] - 38 - INFO - Queue size is 80000
[2017-03-24 20:44:44,026 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-9] - 70 - INFO - Shelve queue sleeps for 100 sec
[2017-03-24 20:44:44,028 - shelve_mp.py - ForkPoolWorker-8] - 70 - INFO - Shelve queue sleeps for 100 sec
```